# Using addprocs() and pmap() inside a function in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

In Julia, I want to use `addprocs` and `pmap` inside a function that is defined inside a module. Here's a silly example:

```
module test

using Distributions

export g, f

function g(a, b)
  a + rand(Normal(0, b))
end

function f(A, b)

  close = false
  if length(procs()) == 1    #  If there are already extra workers,
    addprocs()               #  use them, otherwise, create your own.
    close = true
  end

  W  = pmap(x -> g(x, b), A)

  if close == true
    rmprocs(workers())       #  Remove the workers you created.
  end

  return W

end

end

test.f(randn(5), 1)
```

This returns a very long error

```
WARNING: Module test not defined on process 4
WARNING: Module test not defined on process 3
fatal error on fatal error on WARNING: Module test not defined on process 2
43: : WARNING: Module test not defined on process 5
fatal error on fatal error on 5: 2: ERROR: UndefVarError: test not defined
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:504
 in handle_deserialize at serialize.jl:477
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:696

...

 in message_handler_loop at multi.jl:878
 in process_tcp_streams at multi.jl:867
 in anonymous at task.jl:63
Worker 3 terminated.
Worker 2 terminated.ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file
WARNING: rmprocs: process 1 not removed

Worker 5 terminated.ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file

4-element Array{Any,1}:Worker 4 terminated.ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file


 ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file
ProcessExitedException()
 ProcessExitedException()
 ProcessExitedException()
 ProcessExitedException()
```

What I'm trying to do is write a package that contains functions that perform operations that can be optionally parallelized at the user's discretion. So a function like `f` might take an argument `par::Bool` that does something like I've shown above if the user calls `f` with `par = true` and loops otherwise. So from within the definition of `f` (and within the definition of the module `test`), I want to create workers and broadcast the Distributions package and the function `g` to them.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using `@everywhere` in your function?  The following, for example, works fine on my computer.

```
function f(A, b)

  close = false
  if length(procs()) == 1    #  If there are already extra workers,
    addprocs()               #  use them, otherwise, create your own.
    @everywhere begin
      using Distributions
      function g(a, b)
        a + rand(Normal(0, b))
      end
    end
    close = true
  end

  W  = pmap(x -> g(x, b), A)

  if close == true
    rmprocs(workers())       #  Remove the workers you created.
  end

  return W

end

f(randn(5), 1)
```

Note: when I first ran this, I needed to recompile the `Distributions` package since it had been updated since I had last used it.  When I first tried the above script right after the recompiling, it failed.  But, I then quit Julia and reopened it and it worked fine.  Perhaps that was what is causing your error?

Comment: I think the issue is that `f` is defined in a module. The code you posted does work if I execute it in the REPL. But defining `f` inside a module and then calling `f` does not work. I'll update the question.